# Wordpress: Image name issue after upload to host

Tags: wordpress

I have built a Wordpress eshop using woocommerce plugin, when upload my eshop from local to host all image names changed from εικόνα1.jpg to ???!?!?!.jpg.
eshop is in Greek language encode to utf-8. 
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/filenames-to-latin/) plugin for correct filename el->en rename

Comment: Hi barseon, thanks for your reply, I added the plugin but it doesn't work, is there something more that I must do?